# how to move to the next loop in PARI/GP if I use multi-line nested for loops?

Tags: pari-gp

my question is: how to move to the next loop in PARI/GP if I use multi-line nested for loops ? for example :

if I use this code :

for(K=1,10,for(i=1,5,if(isprime(2*i*prime(K)+1)==1,print(2*i"*"prime(K)))))

and since 2*(i=1)*prime(K=1)+1=5 is prime, I need my machine not to loop for i=2......i=5, I need it to move on to the next K, so:

how to do this on PARI/GP?

and I am sorry if my question is not clear or duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use break. But first, let's clean up the presentation so this is more readable:

```
func()=
{
  for(K=1,10,
    for(i=1,5,
      if(isprime(2*i*prime(K)+1)==1,
        print(2*i"*"prime(K))
      )
    )
  );
}
func()
```

You want to break out of the innermost loop, like so (just giving the function itself):

```
func()=
{
  for(K=1,10,
    for(i=1,5,
      if(isprime(2*i*prime(K)+1)==1,
        print(2*i"*"prime(K));
        break
      )
    )
  );
}
```

But while we're here, there's no need to add `== 1`; `if` is already branching on nonzero values.

```
func()=
{
  for(K=1,10,
    for(i=1,5,
      if(isprime(2*i*prime(K)+1),
        print(2*i"*"prime(K));
        break
      )
    )
  );
}
```

We could also store the value of prime(K) so we don't need to compute it twice. But better yet, let's use a loop directly over the primes so we don't need the `prime()` function at all!

```
func(maxK=10)=
{
  my(K=0);
  forprime(p=2,prime(maxK),
    K++;
    for(i=1,5,
      if(isprime(2*i*p+1),
        print(2*i"*"p);
        break
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Here I have changed the function so you can call it with different maximum values other than 10 and I've kept the index in case you wanted it for some reason. But I think a better approach would be to give a bound on how high you want to go in the primes directly, and forgetting about the prime indexes entirely:

```
func(maxP=29)=
{
  forprime(p=2,maxP,
    for(i=1,5,
      if(isprime(2*i*p+1),
        print(2*i"*"p);
        break
      )
    )
  );
}
```

In both cases I added a default argument so calling `func()` will do the same thing as your original function (except that it now breaks the way you want).

Comment: thank you very much sir, and I am sorry, I can't vote for the answer, because of my reputations number.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if you have other questions.